# How to disable certain controls until update is successful?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, gridview

I'm working with a `GridView` and pretty much everything is working fine.

The only thing left is to make sure that when I'm typing in one text field, all other `text fields` and `Submit` buttons in my `GridView` on other rows except current one get disabled until my update is done.

This is my `GridView`'s generated `html` code:

```
<div id="gridView">
                     <div>
        <table cellspacing="0" border="1" style="border-color:Red;border-collapse:collapse;position:absolute; top: 290px;" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults" rules="all">
            <tbody><tr>
                <th scope="col">ISONUM</th><th scope="col">OFFICE NAME</th><th scope="col">REGION</th><th scope="col">DIVISION</th><th scope="col">EMAIL ADDRESS</th>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>
                                    <span style="display:inline-block;width:70px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvIsoNum_0">222222222 </span>
                                </td><td>
                                    <span style="display:inline-block;width:200px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvIsoOfficeName_0">My Test</span>
                                </td><td>
                                    <span style="display:inline-block;width:50px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvRegion_0">99</span>
                                </td><td>
                                    <span style="display:inline-block;width:50px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvDivision_0">11111</span>
                                </td><td>
                                    <input type="text" style="width:200px;" onclick="ResetMessage();" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvEmailAddress_0" value="mytest@google.com" name="ctl00$MainContent$grvIsoSearchResults$ctl02$txtgvEmailAddress">
                                    <input type="submit" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_btnEmailUpdate_0" value="Update" name="ctl00$MainContent$grvIsoSearchResults$ctl02$btnEmailUpdate">
                                </td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>
                                    <span style="display:inline-block;width:70px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvIsoNum_1">CB2222001 </span>
                                </td><td>
                                    <span style="display:inline-block;width:200px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvIsoOfficeName_1">DENNIS PETROVIC          </span>
                                </td><td>
                                    <span style="display:inline-block;width:50px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvRegion_1"></span>
                                </td><td>
                                    <span style="display:inline-block;width:50px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvDivision_1">99801</span>
                                </td><td>
                                    <input type="text" style="width:200px;" onclick="ResetMessage();" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvEmailAddress_1" value="dennis@dlgent.com" name="ctl00$MainContent$grvIsoSearchResults$ctl03$txtgvEmailAddress">
                                    <input type="submit" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_btnEmailUpdate_1" value="Update" name="ctl00$MainContent$grvIsoSearchResults$ctl03$btnEmailUpdate">
                                </td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>
                                    <span style="display:inline-block;width:70px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvIsoNum_2">FT2222001 </span>
                                </td><td>
                                    <span style="display:inline-block;width:200px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvIsoOfficeName_2">DENNIS PETROVIC          </span>
                                </td><td>
                                    <span style="display:inline-block;width:50px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvRegion_2"></span>
                                </td><td>
                                    <span style="display:inline-block;width:50px;text-align:center" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvDivision_2">99801</span>
                                </td><td>
                                    <input type="text" style="width:200px;" onclick="ResetMessage();" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_txtgvEmailAddress_2" value="dennis@dlgent.com" name="ctl00$MainContent$grvIsoSearchResults$ctl04$txtgvEmailAddress">
                                    <input type="submit" id="MainContent_grvIsoSearchResults_btnEmailUpdate_2" value="Update" name="ctl00$MainContent$grvIsoSearchResults$ctl04$btnEmailUpdate">
                                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div>
```

How can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: Try $( "input" ).prop( "disabled", true ); and sometimes you also have to change the css-property of an element or the parent element to z-index:-1

Comment: Also mention your jquery code .

Comment: I'm using `javascript` `onkeypress` for that one. My GridView is not loaded since it is a part of `UpdatePanel`. So, I'm using `onkeypress`  I need something like foreach textfields that are note being changed, and submit buttons that do not belong to the row where text filed under change, disable textfield and buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code bellow;

```
$(function () {
//this is based on your code only, this could be done a lot prettier if you added a custom attribute to each
// <tr> like let's say - myrownumber ... then there is no need to get a child and find rownumber on the fly, 
//an everything would be prettier; 
$('input').live("focus", function () {

    var rowId = $(this).attr('id');
    var selectedRow = rowId.substring((rowId.length - 1), rowId.length);
    $('tr').each(function () {
        //find rownum 
        var inputId = $(this).find('input').attr('id');

        if (inputId != null && typeof inputId !== "undefined") {
            var row = inputId.substring((inputId.length - 1), inputId.length);

            if (row !== selectedRow) {
                $(this).find('input').prop("disabled", true);
            }
        }
    });

});
//once again this is based on your code, this can be done more ellegantly if you implement smarter naming 
//make all buttons of same class, etc... for easier selection
$('input[type=submit]').live("click", function () {
    //submit your request and get response 
    //if response success 
    $('tr').each(function () {
        $(this).find('input').prop("disabled", false);
    });

});
```

});

Comment: would that work if my `GridView` inside of `UpdatePanel` and is getting rendered on a page?

Comment: see latest edit using live... but yes, all inputs within the page will be scrutinized, regardless of how deep they nested, it's not optimal performance, but you can specify more detailed selectors to improve it, if it matters to you.

Comment: Thank you for your help...I got an error "Object doesn't support property or method 'prop'" and also, I have another input field, that I do not think I need to be a part of a `gridview`.

Comment: What version of jquery to you use? Because ...  As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes. So yeah make sure you use jQuery 1.6+

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @user3380971 I have finalized my solution to the problem:

$(function(){

```
$('input[type="text"]').live("focus", function() {
    var rowId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('tr').each(function(){
        var inputId = $(this).find('input[type="text"]').attr('id');
        var submitId = $(this).closest("tr").find('input[type="submit"]').attr('id');
        alert(submitId);
        if(inputId != null && typeof inputId != "undefined"){
            if(rowId != inputId){               
                $(this).find('input[type="text"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $(this).closest("tr").find('input[type="submit"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
            }
        }
    });                                
});
```

});

Now, I'm disabling text fields and buttons belonging to different rows then onces that belong to the row under update