# How to disable all input fields and submit buttons onkeypress event of a specific textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a `onkeypress` event firing when editing a `textbox`:

.......

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtgvEmailAddress" Text = '<%# Eval("EMAIL")%>' runat="server" Width="200px" onkeypress="DetectUpdate(this)" onclick="ResetMessage();"/>
 <asp:Button ID="btnEmailUpdate" Text = "Update" runat="server" CommandName="UpdateEmail" onClientClick="return ValidateEmail(this);"/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

........

This `textbox` is a part of a `GridView` that is a part of `UpdatePanel`
I have a method that is triggered when `onkeypress` event fires for that particular `textbox`.

Now, I'm looking for the way to disable all other `textboxes` on that `GridView` together with an input fields, so , the user is not able to change them while Update is done

How can this be done?

Thank's

Comment: Can you post your JavaScript function DetectUpdate()?

Comment: I updated my post with the solution but I still need help in something else regarding the same issue. I have posted the question in updated code

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution:

```
 $(function(){

    $('input[type="text"]').live("focus", function() {
        var rowId = $(this).attr('id');
        $('tr').each(function(){
            var inputId = $(this).find('input[type="text"]').attr('id');
            if(inputId != null && typeof inputId != "undefined"){
                if(rowId != inputId){               
                    $(this).find('input[type="text"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            }
        });                                
    });
});
```

here is a link: [How to disable certain controls until update is successful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764918/how-to-disable-certain-controls-until-update-is-successful)
However I still need to also disable all the submit controls that do not belong to the same row as an `textbox` that is being updated

Answer (score 0):

I solved the latest as well by adding the following:

```
$(this).closest("tr").find('input[type="submit"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
```

inside of an inner `if` statement:

```
if(rowId != inputId){               
    $(this).find('input[type="text"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(this).closest("tr").find('input[type="submit"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
}
```